# Mysql 5.6 not using index in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of parents, and a table of children

My parents table is as follows:

```
+----------------+-------------------------------+
|      parent_id | parent_name                   |
+----------------+-------------------------------+
|          10792 |  Katy                         |
|           7562 |  Alex                         |
|          13330 |  Drew                         |
|           9153 |  Brian                        |
+----------------+-------------------------------+
```

My children's table is:

```
+----------+-------------------------------+-----------+-----+
| child_id | child_name                    | parent_id | age |
+----------+-------------------------------+-----------+-----+
|        1 | Matthew                       |     10792 |   4 |
|        2 | Donald                        |      9153 |   5 |
|        3 | Steven                        |     10792 |   9 |
|        4 | John                          |      7562 |   6 |
+----------+-------------------------------+-----------+-----+
```

When I use a sub-select such as:

```
SELECT parent_name, (SELECT SUM(age) FROM children WHERE parent_id = parents.parent_id) AS combined_age FROM parents;
```

My issue is that when I execute this query (parents are 13,000 records, children are 21,000 records) an index of **parent_id** in **children** doesn't get used, as shown in the explain plan. I get:

```
+----+--------------------+--------------------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table                    | type   | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra                                           |
+----+--------------------+--------------------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | parents                  | ALL    | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL  | 13548 | NULL                      
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | children                 | ALL    | PARENTS,AGE   | NULL | NULL    | NULL  | 21654 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x22) |
+----+--------------------+--------------------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

This query is taking over 3 minutes to run, and I can't seem to get the subquery to use an index to query where the children belong to the parent. I tried USE INDEX and FORCE INDEX, as well as USE KEY AND FORCE KEY. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So It turns out this happens when the two ID fields are not the same field type INT(11) VS. VARCHAR(45). In the application, one of the table's ID fields was created strangely. Updating the field type solved the SQL optimizer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The index should be used.  The optimal index would be `children(parent_id, age)`.

You can try re-writing the query as a `join`:

```
select p.parent_name, sum(c.age)
from parents p left join
     children c
     on p.parent_id = c.parent_id
group by p.parent_name;
```